# How is the most efficient way to update an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a ListView with some data that comes from an ObservableCollection and it's updated each 5 min. All elements have their own ID; my question is: how is the right way to update the ObservableCollection? Attributing all the data to ObservableCollection again or using Remove/Insert methods to change only the items that I need update?

Comment: Post some code samples.

Answer (score 1):

There is a "trinity of chaqnge notification" you need with ObservableCollections. Or really collections and XAML/MVVM:

1. Adding and removal of Collection Items. That is the only one ObservableCollection takes care off
2. Notification on each property of the class in the Collection
3. Notification on the property that exposes the Observable Collection.

As the collection raies events on each removal or addition and there is no "AddRange" equivalent, large scale changes usually require de-exposing the collection for a moment. Or even building a new one from scratch, then exposing it.

I think that last case it what you are asking about.

Comment: Yes... data comes done already from the webservice and doesn't makes any sense loop by it to update only a fews elements when I can simply assign the new data to the ObservableCollection

Comment: @Eder: In that case: 1) Create a new ObservableCollection. 2) Build it in code behind. 3) Finally,expose it to via the property. The properties change notification will trigger all the nessesary bindings.